# Interaction between Xamarin & Facebook

Tags: c#, ios, facebook, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm trying to connect to facebook using my xamarin app, and then posting thing.
I got this working so far, however when I use the Map layout for my custom graph story, I cannot attach the coordinates I need to use.

I'm currently using a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, string> results = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"route", DictionaryToJson(routeObject)},
    {"location_start", DictionaryToJson(point1)},
    {"distance", "5.2"},
    {"duration", "01:05:36"},
    {"maxspeed", "12.4"},
    {"message", "Blargh"},
};

var newRequest = new OAuth2Request("POST",
    new Uri("https://graph.facebook.com/me/tracker:obj"),
    results, Account);
```

DictionaryToJson:

```
private string DictionaryToJson(Dictionary<string, string> dict)
{
    var entries = dict.Select(d =>
        string.Format("\"{0}\": \"{1}\"", d.Key, string.Join(",", d.Value)));
    return "{" + string.Join(",", entries) + "}";
}
```

This works fine for all objects that can be converted to a string, however I cannot use this for the GeoPoint collection I need to pass to it, for it to draw the route.

Anyone knows how this can be done? I've been trying to get this working for an entire day by now, and no progress.

Comment: this isn't really a Xamarin issue - it sounds like a basic serialization problem.  What does your server expect the "location_start" argument to look like?

Comment: @Jason the "server" would appear to be Facebook. :)

Comment: Yes, but I have no idea what his "custom graph story" expects for the "location_start" parameter.

Comment: The "field" I'm trying to fill, would be an array of GeoPoints. Which I believe is the GeoPoint class made by Microsoft, seeing as they make the FB map widget. I got the location_start argument to work. It's an entirely different array. Thing is, you can't have duplicate entries in a dictionary, which is what I need to make HTTP arrays. I think. This is exactly why I ask for help ^.^

Comment: Try using a Tuple instead of a Dictionary.  It will allow duplicates.

Comment: I don't know if that would work, it might, had it not been because I can't use it, due to the requirement of OAuth2Request wanting a http method, a URL, and a IDictionary and the Account... Or can I wrap a Tuple in a new class that inherits IDictionary?